# would saml response contains all saml attributes for a user

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

i want to derive role from SAML attributes like 'group' attributes.
my question is , if SAML identity provider would return all SAML attributes in SAML response ?
or i have to do something in SAML authentication request to ask for SAML attributes explicitly ?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity provider and service provider need to agree on what information will be included in the SAML assertion. Typically this is done as part of setting up SSO between the two organizations and prior to any actual SSO. The identity provider needs to know what information you need so they can configure their system to include this information in the SAML assertion.

If there is certain information you need such as user group information then you need to specify this in your requirements to the identity provider. This is not done through the authentication request.